# Get Username with more than 20 characters

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the username from the currently logged in user.
This user comes from a domain and has more than 20 characters as name.

I already tried `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, `Enviroment.UserName` and `SystemInformation.UserName` but they all give me the username trimed to 20 characters.

How can I get the full username?

Comment: Share your code for the same.

Comment: maybe this will be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378739/get-username-without-the-20-char-limit

Comment: I suggest you read this stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036861/error-creating-a-user-with-more-than-20-chars-in-samaccountname-using-net